# Firebase JSON adds integer in tree

Tags: android, json, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm moving my database over to Firebase and I've got things connected up, but I can't seem to get the right format in Firebase (moving from SQLite to Firebase/JSON). I was able to convert my database to JSON and I validated it and imported it, and everything seems fine - except Firebase adds integers in the tree instead of what the headers should be. Like this:
[image]

When I export the JSON, the integers aren't there. What am I missing here?

Comment: See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase, unlike JSON, doesn't support arrays directly.
If you have an array of items in your database, it will represent
the items, as entries, with the index inside of the array, as the key.
When you export it back to JSON, it uses the JSON array representation again.

Comment: Might be worth adding a link to the blog post that describes this behavior: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: I read the article, but it seems to describe how to make Firebase work with your array, not the other way around. How can I edit here to make it work better within Firebase going forward? I have a large amount of existing data (I was using my own database) that I'd like to bring in there, but not sure how.

Comment: This is a solid answer. I needed to think about what I wanted and I don't necessarily care about the exact unique value for each child, just that it IS unique, so numbers work for an initial dump (from arrays) and then I can use push() when receiving user data and that'll be fine.